# In Rust, how can I fix the error "the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Object+'a`"

Tags: rust

With the following code, I am getting a "the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Object+'a`" error. I've trimmed out all the other code not needed to trigger the error.

```
fn main() {
}

pub trait Object {
    fn select(&mut self);
}

pub struct Ball<'a>;

impl<'a> Object for Ball<'a> {
    fn select(&mut self) {
        // Do something
    }
}

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    foo: Vec<Object + 'a>,
}
```

Playpen: http://is.gd/tjDxWl

The full error is:

```
<anon>:15:1: 17:2 error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Object+'a`
<anon>:15 pub struct Foo<'a> {
<anon>:16     foo: Vec<Object + 'a>,
<anon>:17 }
<anon>:15:1: 17:2 note: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` must be implemented because it is required by `collections::vec::Vec`
<anon>:15 pub struct Foo<'a> {
<anon>:16     foo: Vec<Object + 'a>,
<anon>:17 }
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

I'm very new to Rust and don't really know where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is this:

You want to store a vector of Objects.  Now, a vector is a flat array: Each entry comes after another.
But Object is a trait, and while you have only implemented it for Ball, you could implement it for Hats and Triangles too.  But those might be different sized in memory!  So Object, on its own, doesn't have a size.

There are two ways of fixing this:

- Make Foo generic, and only store one type of Object in each Foo.  I have a feeling this may not be what you want.  Playpen: http://is.gd/Y0fatg
- Indirection:  Instead of storing the Objects directly in the array, store Box instead.  Here is a playpen link doing this. http://is.gd/ORkDRC

Comment: Note the third solution: use an `enum` instead of a trait. This closes down the set of types that can be represented, and thus assuming that all are `Sized` it creates a `Sized` `enum`.

Comment: I am adapting this from another selection of code that used the enum method. It worked well, but was not flexible enough for me. Each time I added a new thing that implemented the Object methods, I had to find and change 10-15 places in my code. In simpler code, that works fine, but my changes are starting to outgrow it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Neither of the playpen links you provide compile - Just FYI, as it would be great for answers to include a playpen that did!